# Rails: more efficient way to export many-to-many tables to excel

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have the following models:

```
class Student
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :courses, through: :course_students
  has_many :course_students
end

class Course
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :students, through: :course_students
  has_many :course_students
end

class CourseStudent
  attr_accessible :grade

  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end
```

Now, I'm trying to generate an excel table, with students as rows, and courses as columns, and the intersection will show the student's grade in that course.

So far I was handling small groups of students, so the following algorithm was ok:

```
<table>
  ...
  <tbody>
    <% @students..includes(:courses)each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        ...
        <% student.courses.includes(:course_students).each do |course| %>
          <td><%= course.course_students.find_by_student_id(student.id).try(:grade) || '-' %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>  
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you see, I've been trying to include the courses and the course_students when I load the data, but I still get a ton of queries. I know this is a classic N+1 queries issue (more like NxM+N+M+1), but the usual approach doesn't work.

I was hoping to pull all the data I need in fewer queries. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should collect all courses to some standardized sort order (I'm using `name` arbitrarily, but it can be anything):

```
<% @courses = Course.order(:name) %>
```

You should also generate a header row to display the course columns:

```
<tr>
  ...
  <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <td><%= course.name %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Now, you'll need to iterate over each student (eager-loading the :course_student join models to avoid N+1)

```
<% @students.includes(:course_students).each do |student| %>
  <tr>
    ...
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
      <td><%= student.course_students.detect do |cs| 
                cs.course_id == course.id
              end.try(:grade) || '-' %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>  
<% end %>
```

You can optimize this a bit more by avoiding the call to `detect` and building a grades hash for each student:

```
    ...
    <% grades = student.course_students.each_with_object(Hash.new('-')) do |cs, hash| 
         hash[cs.course_id] = cs.grade
       end %>
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
      <td><%= grades[course.id] %></td>
    <% end %>
    ...
```